# Compilation error when using package media9/ VPlayer.swf

Tags: errors, packages, media9

I'm using media9 package with MikTeX 4.0 and TeXstudio 2.12.22 , but when I try to compile there are 2 errors.

> Package media9 Error: Line 217: File `imagenes/videosmp4/3dWS-DD.mp4' not(media9) found. ]{}{VPlayer.swf}

> Undefined control sequence. ]{}{VPlayer.swf}

I have read media9 documentation in this webpage
https://gitlab.com/agrahn/media9/-/blob/master/doc/media9.pdf
I have install media9 package, l3kernel, l3package, I'm using pdfTeX, I have already installed Ghostscript 9.52 (from this website https://www.ghostscript.com/download/gsdnld.html), I have Adobe Reader, but I'm not sure about dvipdfmx, how can I know If I have the correct version?

Anyway, I can't compile, I don't know what should I do. I'm a beginner in LaTeX world.

This is my code:

```
\documentclass[12pt,openright, twoside]{report}


\usepackage{media9}
\begin{document}

\includemedia[
label=some_dice,
width=0.6\linewidth,height=0.45\linewidth,
addresource=imagenes/videosmp4/3dWS-DD.mp4, 
transparent, 
activate=pageopen,
passcontext, 
flashvars={
   source=imagenes/videosmp4/3dWS-DD.mp4
   &loop=true
}
]{}{VPlayer.swf}
\mediabutton[
mediacommand=some_dice:playPause,
overface=\color{blue}{\fbox{\strut Play/Pause}},
downface=\color{red}{\fbox{\strut Play/Pause}}
]{\fbox{\strut Play/Pause}}
\mediabutton[
mediacommand=some_dice:setSource [(imagenes/videosmp4/3dWS-DD.mp4)]
]{\fbox{\strut imagenes/videosmp4/3dWS-DD.mp4}}

\end{document}
```

Help! :P
Thank u!

Comment: Hi and welcome. Please give a fully compilable code.

Comment: Sure, I wrote it as an answer, thank you.

Comment: Please place this code in your question by clicking on the `edit` button instead of completing your question in the answer section.

Comment: Ok, sorry, thank you.

Comment: Please now remove unnecessary packages in order to have an MWE as explained here :  [How to make a “minimum example”](https://www.texfaq.org/FAQ-minxampl)

Comment: Ok, I did it. Thank you.

Comment: If you have installed a `MikTeX` or `TeXlive` distribution, you do not need to do any further installation. You don't have to install Ghostscript 9.52 or anything else. Everything is included in these distributions. I quote from the `media9` documentation `MiKTEX and TEXLive users should run the package manager for installation and updates`.

Comment: @Kelly There are a number of examples in the manual where you just need to replace the video file name in the code.

Comment: @AndréC
Ok, I noticed that in the last code I didn't write the word _source_, but then I write it, try to compile and It didn't work. Now, I have changed the code but I still have the same problem. I already updated _media9_ package in _MikTeX_

Comment: @AlexG, yeah, I based on the manual :(, but I still have the same problem. I don't know If the problem is my computer.

Comment: @KellyHernández Uninstall what you've installed unnecessarily (Gosthscript and the rest) and update your question with the latest changes you've made and explaining what you've actually done. Tell AlexG (maintainer of this package) the references of the code you took from the manual (page, etc).